# Can't send params (variables and one hardcoded value) to prefilled form in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, soap, savon

I am building a Rails 4 app which interacts heavily with a SOAP XML webservice. I am successfully making requests to the webservice with Savon using models inside the app.

But now I want to simply pass variables (and one hardcoded value) from the result of one request to pre-fill a form on another page before the user clicks submit and makes another request. I am doing this through an edit link at the moment. When I click on this it automatically calls the webservice (displaying an error message) - I don't want to call it at all at this stage.

I'm guessing that I can solve this somehow by changing the model and/or controller but I'm really stuck right now.

My view page which displays results from first request. (I need to send all the data in the edit link, which is very long):

```
<% if @search %>
  <dl id ="reservation_info">

    <h3><%= @search.restaurant_name %></h3>
    <h4><%= @search.restaurant_phone_number %></h4>
   <!--  HIDDEN -->
    <% @search.restaurant_id %>

    <dd>Booking ref: <%= @search.confirmation_number %></dd>

    <!--  FOR CANCELLATION: -->
    <% @search.reservation_id %>
    <% @search.allowed_to_cancel_online %>

    <dt><strong>Time / Date</strong></dt>
    <dd><%= @search.dining_date_and_time %></dd>

    <dt><strong>Guests</strong></dt>
    <dd><%= @search.size %></dd>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', guests_reservations_path(:partner_code => "DEV-DAN-BETH:73411"), restaurant_location_id: @search.location_id, session_id: @search.session_id, dining_date_and_time: @search.dining_date_and_time, first_name: @search.first_name, last_name: @search.last_name, email: @search.email, :method => :post %>

    <dt><strong>Area</strong></dt>
    <dd><%= @search.location_name %></dd>
    <!--  HIDDEN -->
    <% @search.location_id %>

    <dt><strong>Your details:</strong></dt>
    <dd><%= @search.first_name %></dd>
    <dd><%= @search.last_name %></dd>
    <dd><%= @search.session_id %></dd>
    <dd><%= @search.email %></dd>    

  </dl>
<% end %>
```

Form which needs to be pre-filled / pre-populated:

```
<%= form_tag(reservations_path, method: :post) %>

  <!-- ALWAYS HIDDEN FIELDS -->
  <div class="field">    
    <%= text_field_tag :partner_code %>
  </div>  
  <div class="field">    
   <%= text_field_tag :restaurant_location_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">    
    <%= text_field_tag :session_id %>
  </div>

  <!-- ACTION FIELDS -->
  <div class="field">    
    <%= label_tag :dining_date_and_time %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :dining_date_and_time %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">    
    <%= label_tag :size, 'Guests' %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :size %>
  </div>

  <!-- HIDDEN PERSONAL DETAILS -->
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :first_name %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :first_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :last_name %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :last_name %>
  </div>  
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :email %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :email %>
  </div>  

  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag 'Continue', name: nil %>
  </div>
```

1st request controller (not the best practice I know, but this is the only way it works, already tried to refactor it).:

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
    def index   
      if params[:confirmation_number] && params[:email]           
      end
    end

    def show
    @search = Search.new params[:confirmation_number], params[:email]
    end   

  private 

    def search_params
      params.require(:search).permit(:confirmation_number, :email)
    end

end
```

Controller for second request (Guest is empty as not sure what to do there):

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController

    def index
      if params[:partner_code] && params[:restaurant_location_id] && params[:session_id] && params[:dining_date_and_time] && params[:size] && params[:first_name] && params[:last_name] && params[:email]
      end
    end

    def show
      @reservation = Reservation.new params[:partner_code], params[:restaurant_location_id], params[:session_id], params[:dining_date_and_time], params[:size], params[:first_name], params[:last_name], params[:email]
    end

    def guest    
    end

    private

    def reservation_params
      params.require(:reservation).permit(:partner_code, :restaurant_location_id, :session_id, :dining_date_and_time, :size, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :confirmation_number)
    end

end
```

2nd request model (the one which is calling automatically) Also, N.B Active Record inheritance is redundant here as values are not being saved to DB when webservice is called / form posted:

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :confirmation_number, :reservation_id, :dining_date_and_time, :size, :session_id, :first_name, :last_name, :confirmation_number, :allowed_to_cancel_online, :restaurant_phone_number, :restaurant_id, :restaurant_name, :location_id, :location_name, :email

  def client
    Savon.client(wsdl: "http://wsdl-example-uri", follow_redirects: :follow_redirects)
  end

  def initialize(partner_code, restaurant_location_id, session_id, dining_date_and_time, size, first_name, last_name, email)
    message = {'PartnerCode' => partner_code, 'RestaurantLocationId' => restaurant_location_id, 'SessionId' => session_id, 'DiningDateAndTime' => dining_date_and_time, 'Size' => size}
    message.merge!('Booker' => {'UserWithoutALogin' => {'FirstName' => first_name, 'LastName' => last_name, 'EMail' => email}})

    response = client.call(:book_reservation, message: message)
    if response.success?
      data = response.to_array(:book_reservation_response).first
      if data
        @confirmation_number = data[:confirmation_number]
        @reservation_id = data[:reservation_id]
      end
    else
      errors.add "Failed to make SOAP request"
    end
  end


end
```

Comment: Also if I change the :method in the edit link to :get, it just displays the empty form on my guest page.

Answer (score 1):

#### Set up boundries!

When dealing with API's and web services - it can be tempting to do it on the model layer - you add a little `fetch_from_facebook` method and start whittling out `attributes_from_facebook` methods and so forth. But this is a huge anti-pattern as it creates strong couplings between your application and the external service.

You definitely NEVER want to call an external service in the initialize method of your model as it will make testing extremely difficult. And you should ALMOST NEVER override the initialize method of an ActiveRecord model. If you do your models should at least have the expected interface:

```
def initialize(hash = {}, &block)
end
```

Don't be that guy - be nice to your fellow devs and respect the principle of least surprise.

Instead use [service objects (plain old ruby objects)](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services) to handle fetching data from remote services.

Also if you are not saving to the database don't use ActiveRecord for you models! Instead just use a plain ruby class and `include ActiveModel::Model`.

#### What about forms?

Rails has many built in form helpers which make it easy to bind form inputs to a model instance:

```
<%= form_form(@reservation) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">    
    <%= f.label_tag :dining_date_and_time %><br>
    <%= f.text_field_tag :dining_date_and_time %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

See [RailsGuides: Form Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-model-objects). I would consider taking a break and do a [basic tutorial of setting up a CRUD app](https://www.railstutorial.org/) before you continue on with you project. Dealing with external data sources is tricky and you need a solid foundation to start on.

## Edit

This is an example of how you would use services to deal with interacting with an external API:

```
class PushReservationService 

  # Use dependency injection so we can mock the client in tests
  def initialize(client = nil)
    @client = client || Savon.client(
      wsdl: "http://wsdl-example-uri", 
      follow_redirects: :follow_redirects
    )
  end

  # return [reservation]
  def call(reservation, **kwargs, &block)
     # set default options
    message = kwargs.merge(
      'PartnerCode' => reservation.partner_code, 
      'RestaurantLocationId' => reservation.restaurant_location_id, 
      'SessionId' => reservation.session_id, 
      'DiningDateAndTime' => reservation.dining_date_and_time, 
      'Size' => reservation.size
    )
    response = @client.call(:book_reservation, message: message)
    if response.success?
      data = response.to_array(:book_reservation_response).first
      if data
        reservation.assign_attributes(
          confirmation_number: data[:confirmation_number]
          reservation_id: data[:reservation_id]
        )
        yield reservation, data if block_given? 
        reservation.save
        return true
      end
    end
    false
  end
end
```

Calling them from your controller is pretty easy:

```
def create
  @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)
  if @reservation.save
    service = PushReservationService.new
    if service.call(@reservation)
      redirect_to @reservation, notice: 'Confirmed!'
    else 
      # @todo strategy for dealing with failed confirmation.
      flash[:alert] = 'Your reservation was created but we could not confirm your reservation.'
      redirect_to edit_reservation_path(@reservation)
    end
  else 
    # render form again so that user can correct basic validation errors like a wrong email
    render :new
  end
end
```

This is basically how I would do based on my experience of dealing with SOAP based payment systems.

Within your boundaries everything is a run of the mill Rails app. Only your services have to deal with the huge PITA that is SOAP and the eccentricities of whatever API you are dealing with.

Comment: thanks for your link on service objects. I understand how to build basic CRUD apps. I tried using the standard form do f syntax you present but it got me into all sorts of difficulties so I went back to basic form/text_field tags etc.

Comment: Also in his Rails Cast, Ryan Bates uses the initialize method: http://railscasts.com/episodes/290-soap-with-savon?view=asciicast granted it is not an active record model but I've taken that out now

Comment: That railscast is from 2011 - thats like 50 years ago in Rails years. We have come a long way since then - especially when it comes to best practices.

Comment: You can use the value option on the input helpers to bind the values but I would consider actually trying to solve the "difficulties" you had with form_for instead since it will be less hackish

Comment: I feel like before I embark on a massive project of refactoring (primarily substantial changes to model and controller), I should try to solve the problem at hand ie. passing param values to prefill a new form page. After that I can clean up my code.

Comment: The only two options you have for passing data between requests without using a persistence layer is session based storage and http (form params via post or query params) which both are not very good options for what you are trying to do. You might need to use a persistence layer which could be something simple like Redis or full RDBMS. Creating a hack to make it work without is going to be a lot of wasted work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84388/discussion-between-daneasterman-and-max).

Comment: hi max, as I wrote in chat:
I am now successfully passing values returned from the api to prefill the form but there is one value I need to make the second request which isn't present in the response from the first request - email - but I can grab this from when the user enters it in the first stage
if I create two models - one for the api (in services) and one for the relational db management system (I'm using postgres) - in broad terms will that work?

Comment: I added an example of how I generally would go about refactoring.

Comment: Thanks Max, your example was useful and I'm sure it will make my app much more robust. Appreciate it.

Comment: One final question Max: why is it better to use SQL / Active Record rather than store values from user using HTML5 localStorage or sessionStorage?